# javascript disable text selection but allow dragging

Tags: javascript, text, drag-and-drop, preventdefault

I am fighting this issue for a while now and all my searches leads to use preventDefault() in my onmousedown listener (to prevent text selection), but when I do so, it is also disabling my dragging (can't drag elements even if they have the draggable="true" attribute).

what is the best way to allow dragging elements (using the attribute draggable="true") and when dragging them and hovering with the mouse over some text (p, h1 ,h2...) prevent the text background form being blue (you know - the default when clicking and marking text)

Thanks.
Jim.

Comment: Is this perhaps the answer for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429827/how-can-i-prevent-text-element-selection-with-cursor-drag

Comment: I understand now that my problem is a bit trickier..
I saw this question before and tried it, it does solve this issue, but not my issue. this will lead me to the solutions though :) Thanks @trainoasis

Answer (score 1):

The thing that eventually solved my issue was very simple and in CSS,

you can see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805684/javascript-disable-text-select)

Comment: That's not a solution, I don't want to disable text selection, I just want to disable selected text from being dragged together with the draggable or otherwise clear selection before dragging.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

Just add `onmousedown="mouseDown()"` to your element and this method:

```
function mouseDown() {
   window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}
```

This will unselect all previous selections and only highlight the current element being dragged.